# Symfony2 get serialized object in one to many relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I get serialized cardPrices in jsonSerialize method? id is `OneToMany` relation with CardPrice but how to get this prices? `'price' => $this->getId()->getPriceNet()` does not work.

**CustomerCardSubtype.php**

```
class CustomerCardSubtype implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * Primary key.
     *
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CardPrice", mappedBy="customerCardSubtype")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'description' => $this->getDescription(),
        'name' => $this->getName()
    ];
}
```

**CardPrice.php**

```
class CardPrice implements \JsonSerializable
{

    /**
     * CustomerCardSubtype.
     *
     * @var CustomerCardSubtype
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomerCardSubtype")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_card_subtype_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="RESTRICT")
     */
    private $customerCardSubtype;

/**
 * Get priceNet.
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getPriceNet()
{
    return $this->priceNet;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the usage of [Doctrine Association Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html); `id` should be (and is) an integer, so you cannot call a method on it. This will not work:

```
'price' => $this->getId()->getPriceNet()
```

Instead, create a property (and optionally get/set methods) for the association itself.

Your `CustomerCardSubtype` should look something like this:

```
<?php

class CustomerCardSubtype implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * Primary key.
     *
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Association.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CardPrice", mappedBy="customerCardSubtype")
     */
    private $cardPrice;

    /**
     * @param CardPrice $cardPrice
     */
    public function setCardPrice($cardPrice)
    {
        $this->cardPrice = $cardPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @return CardPrice
     */
    public function getCardPrice()
    {
        return $this->cardPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getId(),
            'description' => $this->getDescription(),
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'price' => $this->cardPrice->getPriceNet()
        ];
    }
}
```

You should now be able to call the `getPriceNet` method on the associated object. If you want to `json_encode` the whole `CardPrice` object as a nested element, you can also implement `JsonSerializable` on that too. Hope this helps.

Comment: shouldn't that last line of code be `'price' => $this->cardPrice->getPriceNet()` instead?